# Fast Iterative GCD

Tags: algorithm

I have GCD(n, i) where i=1 is increasing in loop by 1 up to n. Is there any algorithm which calculate all GCD's faster than naive increasing and compute GCD using Euclidean algorithm?

PS I've noticed if n is prime I can assume that number from 1 to n-1 would give 1, because prime number would be co-prime to them. Any ideas for other numbers than prime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ implementation, works in O(n * log log n) (assuming size of integers are O(1)):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void find_gcd(int n, int *gcd) {
  // divisor[x] - any prime divisor of x
  //              or 0 if x == 1 or x is prime
  int *divisor = new int[n + 1];
  memset(divisor, 0, (n + 1) * sizeof(int));

  // This is almost copypaste of sieve of Eratosthenes, but instead of
  // just marking number as 'non-prime' we remeber its divisor.
  // O(n * log log n)
  for (int x = 2; x * x <= n; ++x) {
    if (divisor[x] == 0) {
      for (int y = x * x; y <= n; y += x) {
        divisor[y] = x;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int x = 1; x <= n; ++x) {
    if (n % x == 0) gcd[x] = x;
    else if (divisor[x] == 0) gcd[x] = 1; // x is prime, and does not divide n (previous line)
    else {
      int a = x / divisor[x], p = divisor[x]; // x == a * p
      // gcd(a * p, n) = gcd(a, n) * gcd(p, n / gcd(a, n))
      // gcd(p, n / gcd(a, n)) == 1 or p
      gcd[x] = gcd[a];
      if ((n / gcd[a]) % p == 0) gcd[x] *= p;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int *gcd = new int[n + 1];
  find_gcd(n, gcd);
  for (int x = 1; x <= n; ++x) {
    printf("%d:\t%d\n", x, gcd[x]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's what I was looking for. Could you expalin me what does make commented out code in last for statement inside find_gcd function - or it's irrelevant (just part of some other algorithm)?

Comment: These two commented out lines were supposed to be an explanation (or prove of correctness maybe) of what I do in next two lines - it's not a code. I thought it will be helpful to add them, but it seems it's misleading :) They're irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

### SUMMARY

The possible answers for the gcd consist of the factors of n.

You can compute these efficiently as follows.

### ALGORITHM

First factorise n into a product of prime factors, i.e. n=p1^n1*p2^n2*..*pk^nk.

Then you can loop over all factors of n and for each factor of n set the contents of the GCD array at that position to the factor.

If you make sure that the factors are done in a sensible order (e.g. sorted) you should find that the array entries that are written multiple times will end up being written with the highest value (which will be the gcd).

### CODE

Here is some Python code to do this for the number 1400=2^3*5^2*7:

```
prime_factors=[2,5,7]
prime_counts=[3,2,1]
N=1
for prime,count in zip(prime_factors,prime_counts):
    N *= prime**count

GCD = [0]*(N+1)
GCD[0] = N
def go(i,n):
    """Try all counts for prime[i]"""
    if i==len(prime_factors):
        for x in xrange(n,N+1,n):
            GCD[x]=n
        return
    n2=n
    for c in xrange(prime_counts[i]+1):
        go(i+1,n2)
        n2*=prime_factors[i]
go(0,1)    
print N,GCD
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary GCD algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

is faster than Euclidean algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

I implemented "gcd()" in C for type "__uint128_t" (with gcc on Intel i7 Ubuntu), based on iterative Rust version:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Iterative_version_in_Rust

Determining number of trailing 0s was done efficiently with "__builtin_ctzll()". I did benchmark 1 million loops of two biggest 128bit Fibonacci numbers (they result in maximal number of iterations) against gmplib "mpz_gcd()" and saw 10% slowdown. Utilizing the fact that u/v values only decrease, I switched to 64bit special case "_gcd()" when "<=UINT64_max" and now see speedup of 1.31 over gmplib, for details see:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=311893&p=1873552#p1873552

```
inline int ctz(__uint128_t u)
{
  unsigned long long h = u;
  return (h!=0) ?      __builtin_ctzll( h )
                : 64 + __builtin_ctzll( u>>64 );
}

unsigned long long _gcd(unsigned long long u, unsigned long long v)
{
  for(;;) {
    if (u > v) { unsigned long long a=u; u=v; v=a; }

    v -= u;

    if (v == 0)  return u;

    v >>= __builtin_ctzll(v);
  }
}

__uint128_t gcd(__uint128_t u, __uint128_t v)
{
       if (u == 0) { return v; }
  else if (v == 0) { return u; }

  int i = ctz(u);  u >>= i;
  int j = ctz(v);  v >>= j;
  int k = (i < j) ? i : j;

  for(;;) {
    if (u > v) { __uint128_t a=u; u=v; v=a; }

    if (v <= UINT64_MAX)  return _gcd(u, v) << k;

    v -= u;

    if (v == 0)  return u << k;

    v >>= ctz(v);
  }
}
```